# Export HTML table to CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I am making a script which gets a table from your mail and puts it into a CSV file.

This is the code I use to transfer my html table to CSV

```
$html = str_get_html($outputstr);   

// For Excel
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');

// Download File
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sample.csv');

$fp = fopen("php://output", "w");

// Take out empty lines
foreach($html->find('tr') as $element) {
    $td = array();

    foreach( $element->find('th') as $row) {
        $td [] = $row->plaintext;
    }

    foreach( $element->find('td') as $row) {
        $td [] = $row->plaintext;
    }

    fputcsv($fp, $td);
}

fclose($fp);
```

The only problem that I'm getting is that when I am opening the CSV file, some of the empty *columns* have a strange character:

[image: as]

I cannot read through with my PHP script to export it to a database

```
fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t");
```

How can I fix this problem?

Do I fix this by modifying the code on the part where I create the CSV file or where I read the CSV file when I'm transferring it to a MySQL database?

When I use an online html to CSV converter it works fine and I am not facing this issue then.

If there is any code needed then I'd love to share it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your charset to UTF-8? Additionally, you're not setting this up as a CSV with your header, instead it is an Excel file.

```
header("content-type:application/csv;charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: Hey, I appreciate your effort, but nothing changed in the CSV file.